# Show that the function $f(x,y)$ admits derivatives

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have this function:
$$f(x,y)=\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$$ when $(x,y)$ is not equal to $(0,0)$
and $$f(x,y)=0$$ when $(x,y)$ is equal to $(0,0)$.
$$$$
What I have to do is:

1. Show that my function admits dervates after any direction in the point (0,0);
2. Find its partial derivates in (0,0);
3. Calculate it's derivate after the direction $s=(\frac{\sqrt3}{2},\frac{1}{2})$;
   $$$$
   For 1. I have used this formulas to show that the function admits derivate after any direction in the point (0,0):
   $$\frac{df}{dx}(0,0)=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x}$$
   and for y
   $$\frac{df}{dy}(0,0)=\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{f(0,y)-f(0,0)}{y}$$
   The first question comes here. How do I solve those limits? Can I just say that they are 0(I mean its $\frac{x^20}{x^2+0}$)?
   $$$$
   For 2. I have just derivated the function, than i substituted $x,y$ with $0,0$. The second question comes here. I got this:
   $$\frac{df}{dx}(0,0)=\frac{2xy[1-x(x+y)]}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$ and I don't think that I'm allowed to substitute $x,y$ with $0,0$.
   Can someone help me and put me back on the right track?(I also would realy appreciate a hint for 3.)

Comment: $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial  x}(0,0)$ not $\dfrac{df}{dx}(0,0)dx$.

Comment: Yes $\dfrac{x^20}{x^2+0}$ is true

Comment: For 2. Your derivation valid only for $\neq(0,0)$.

Comment: This note http://www.math.jhu.edu/mathcourses/202/Florin_notes/differentiability.pdf always helps me to sort out the definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $s=(a,b)$ a direction.

The directional derivative in $(0,0)$ in this direction is given

by

$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(t(a,b))-f(0,0)}{t}$.

For 1. , you have to show that the above limmit exists.

To 2.: for $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial  x}(0,0)$ let $(a,b)=(1,0)$ and for  $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial  y}(0,0)$ let $(a,b)=(0,1)$

Comment: Where the $t$ comes from? And also, what do you mean by $(a,b)=(1,0)$, do you want to say that i have to substitute $x,y$ with $1,0$?

Comment: What is your definition of  a directional derivative ?